# Sphinx not rebuild on read only database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx, master-slave

I am using master/slave databases for my app and have 2 slave , one for sphinx and one for users and as per rule 1 master

Slave databases are set read only. Issue is that when I rebuild sphinx on slave it gives an error

```
The MySQL server is running with the --read-only option so it cannot execute this statement
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Can you share the command you're running and the full output of it, not just the error?

Comment: @pat command i use is rake ts:rebuild

Comment: Are you using deltas? Because deltas require write access when indexing (to reset the delta flag)

Comment: yes we are using delta.... is there any other way also without delta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As determined in the comments, this is happening because delta indices are in play, and they require write access as part of resetting the delta flag columns when running a full index.

If you wish to persist with read-only access, you could investigate [real-time indices](https://freelancing-gods.com/thinking-sphinx/v4/real_time.html) as an alternative to SQL-backed indices with deltas, as real-time indices allow updates as the underlying ActiveRecord data changes. If you're running Thinking Sphinx v4, then the rake tasks won't change at all, you just need to use the different index types.

If you're using TS v3, then the tasks were named differently (`regenerate` instead of `rebuild`, `generate` instead of `index`). [The documentation does distinguish between the two major releases](https://freelancing-gods.com/thinking-sphinx/v3/real_time.html).

But yes, if you wish to continue with SQL-backed indices and deltas, then write access to the database is necessary.

Comment: can you please tell how can I comment resetting the delta flag columns query... i will do it manually using bash

Comment: basically i want to comment this query  resetting the delta flag columns

Comment: and update through bash task or any other, directly on master db

Comment: I see you've asked this question on the GitHub repo, and so I've answered there with some detail: https://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx/issues/1128

Answer (score 0):

What I have done is that remove update delta query form thinking sphinx config by overriding class

```
class ReadOnlyDeltas < ThinkingSphinx::Deltas::DefaultDelta
  def reset_query
   nil
  end
end
```

and extend models with this class

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :table_name, :with => :active_record, :delta => ReadOnlyDeltas do
```

Now what happend is that when I re_index or rebuild sphinx , it works fine on slave db also.

To update delta I write a script in ruby which update all deltas on master after 5 minutes using cronjob